# Check if one value in one column is in another column

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to check if the dates in the `Date2 column` match the dates in the `Date1 column` and which dates do not match. As you can see for the first 25 it matches, but in the end there are 10 rows empty which means that these values are missing.

[image]

I tried:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2:C3020;B2:C3037;C2;TRUE)
```

However that only gives me `#REF!` back.

Is there probably another way to find out which dates do not match?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2;$B$2:$B$3037;1;FALSE)
```

just write it in `D2` cell and stretch it down until `D3037`. If an exact match of date from column `C` is not found in column `B`, the error value `#N/A` is returned.

To get `FOUND` and `NOT FOUND` values you can use modification of this formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C2;$B$2:$B$3037;1;FALSE));"NOT FOUND";"FOUND")
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer! For the `ISERROR` function I get `you've entered too many arguments for this function`. Shouldn`t I put it into an if?

Comment: It should be IFERROR()

Comment: @Cris, not exacty. IFERROR returns value if not error, and, i.e. "Not found" in the other way. But I'd like to return "Found" and "Not found" (not the value). But it's also appropriate way.

Comment: besides your look no hands approach with no explanation, not only that, but you used semicolons instead of commas..which seems to give an error, you need commas, or, what version of excel do you have or what setting do you have that uses semicolons to separate actual parameters(arguments) to a function?

Comment: @barlop, it's based on the regional settings of the OS; if the delimiter for decimals is a comma, Excel takes semicolons as parameter separators

Comment: What can we add in the formula, if the match found then leave the cell blank ?

Answer (score 3):

```
 =IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(B2,$A:$A,1,FALSE)=B2,"True"),"False")
```

This can work without specifying the exact length of column B

Answer (score 2):

```
For instance, consider column values namely A and B

A   B
124 23
244 544
343 244
243 124
566 
677 

To check one value (124) in one column (B) is in another column (A)

=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2, $B$2:$B$5, 1, FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(A2,  $B$2:$B$5, 1, FALSE))

A   B   C
124 23  124
244 544 244
343 244
243 124
566 
677
```

Comment: This result actually returns the value of A if its was found B. This is very helpful because afterward you can copy the result column (C) and paste into another column (D) and PASTE SPECIAL - paste values. Then if you go to DATA > FILTER you can hide blank cells and end up with a column of only the values that were matches.

Comment: ALSO, see S.De's answer for how to select all the values from the column: instead of $B2:$B5, use $B:$B