# Checking to see if two rows have similar data in excel

Tags: excel

I want to compare data in two excel cells (from two columns) and write the matching values only to third column. 
I have two lists of countries, column B has roughly 120 countries while column A has roughly 192 countries. I can't figure out a way to display the countries that correspond with each other (seeing if B belongs in A).

Here is an example of what I pulled off from another thread and it doesn't work for me. 
[excel question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062763/check-if-one-value-in-one-column-is-in-another-column)

Now, here is my spreadsheet. 
[My spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eLpR.png)
I just want to validate and compress the countries that are listed in column B to see if they match Column A and print them in C.

Please let me know how I would do so?

Thanks,

Comment: *"and if they do, print it out"*. Print what out?

Comment: I meant if they match display it in column C. I guess that was pointless to add.

Comment: Display *what* in column C? The country name? Text that says "Match found"? etc. What do you want the output to be?

Comment: I want the output to be the country. If the country (Ecuador, for example) from column B  is in column A then I want it to be displayed in column C. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula in cell `C1` and drag down as far as necessary.

```
= IF(SUMPRODUCT((B1=A$1:A$192)+0)>0,B1,"")
```

This formula returns the country name in the cell next to it if the country exists in the `A` column, and blank otherwise.

[image]

Comment: That makes sense but for some reason it still doesn't display the countries in C it just gives 0's. The countries are in their and Ecuador for example is in column A and B but it is not displayed?

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. It is working for me. See my post, I attached an image showing it gives the expected result.

Comment: I am looking at my data and Thailand is in A204 and in B109 but it still gives a 0.

Comment: I will try and revise my data. Thank you!

Comment: **face palm** Your original post said 192 countries so I made the range `A$1:A$192`. If your data extends beyond that, you need to change the range accordingly (i.e. to *at least* `A$1:A$204`).

Comment: I'd always prefer `COUNTIF` over `SUMPRODUCT` where possible, and you can use the whole column with no downside, e.g. `=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,B1),B1,"")`

Comment: @barryhoudini Thanks. I usually find myself going with `SUMPRODUCT` because it is just in general more versatile. But yea, good point that `COUNTIF` is more efficient